# how to append the nested ul

Tags: jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova-3

My Sqlite Database Data:-

```
ID       ParentId       Item

1           0           Food

2           1           Indian

3           2           Full Meal

4           2           Meal

5           4           Roti

6           4           Dal

7           0           Chinese

8           7           Soup

9           8           Momo

10          9           Noodle
```

In Jquery:-

```
for ( var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
    var food_Id = results.rows.item(i).ID ;
    var food_PId = results.rows.item(i).ParentId;
    var food_Item = results.rows.item(i).Item;
        if(food_PId == 0){
            sfoodID = food_Id;
            foodscripts +=  '<li><a href="#" class="d-main-menu">'
                            +'<img src="images/1.png" class="e-left" />'
                            +'<span class="d-menu-parent-text e-left">'+food_Item+'</span></a>'
        }else{
            foodscripts += '<ul>'
            for(var j = 0; j < results.rows.length; j++ ){
                var food_Id_s = results.rows.item(j).ID ;
                var food_PId_s = results.rows.item(j).ParentId ;
                var food_Item_s = results.rows.item(j).Item;
                    if(sfoodID == food_PId_s){
                        foodscripts += '<li><a href="">'+food_Item_s+'</a></li>'
                    }
            }   
            foodscripts += '</ul>'
        }   
    foodscripts +=  '</li>'
}
```

please help me out if i dont now how many level is there

upto one level i have did it and

how to do for two or three sub level inside that level only

Comment: your question is not more clear.please elaborate what you actually want?

Comment: You wanted that in `JQueryMobile listview` style?

Comment: @BluAngel yes i want in jqueryMobile listview style

Comment: @AtulDhanuka i added answer check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i setup a **[`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/LdVzN/1/)** where adding nested `ul` with your provided data.
You have to need some changes i get data from dummy source like this

```
var dataArray = new Array();
var data = new Array();data['ID'] = 1;data['ParentId'] = 0;data['Item'] = 'Food';dataArray.push(data);
var data = new Array();data['ID'] = 2;data['ParentId'] = 1;data['Item'] = 'Indian';dataArray.push(data);
var data = new Array();data['ID'] = 3;data['ParentId'] = 2;data['Item'] ='Full Meal';dataArray.push(data);
var data = new Array();data['ID'] = 4;data['ParentId'] = 2;data['Item'] = 'Meal';dataArray.push(data);
var data = new Array();data['ID'] = 5;data['ParentId'] = 4;data['Item'] = 'Roti';dataArray.push(data);
var data = new Array();data['ID'] = 6;data['ParentId'] = 4;data['Item'] ='Dal';dataArray.push(data);
var data = new Array();data['ID'] = 7;data['ParentId'] = 0;data['Item'] = 'Chinese';dataArray.push(data);
var data = new Array();data['ID'] = 8;data['ParentId'] = 7;data['Item'] = 'Soup';dataArray.push(data);
var data = new Array();data['ID'] = 9;data['ParentId'] = 8;data['Item'] ='Momo';dataArray.push(data);
var data = new Array();data['ID'] = 10;data['ParentId'] = 9;data['Item'] = 'Noodle';dataArray.push(data);


var food_Id = dataArray[i].ID;
var food_PId = dataArray[i].ParentId;
var food_Item = dataArray[i].Item;
```

Instead of this

```
var food_Id = results.rows.item(i).ID ;
var food_PId = results.rows.item(i).ParentId;
var food_Item = results.rows.item(i).Item;
```

Comment: if you need `lists` in simple style not in `JQueryMobile` style then remove `data-role="listview" attribute`

Comment: thank for the answer finally i got the answer and please like my question also